# Consulta ultimo registro a traves de linq

Tags: c#, entity-framework, linq

Tengo que obtener el registro mas actualizado desde la siguiente tabla

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

para la consulta del registro mas actualizado (el de fecha mas reciente) tengo la siguiente sentencia

```
contexto.Set<Tabla1>().LastOrDefault(x => x.Id_Registro == idRegistro);
```

esta correcta esta forma de consultar por este ultimo registro? o tengo que aplicar otro filtro a la consulta? en este caso, como deberia hacer este filtro?

Saludos y gracias

Comment: Cuando dices el registro más actualizado ¿te refieres a la fila cuyo campo `Fecha` sea el mayor?

Comment: disculpen por el desconocimento pero... a que se refiere la palabra "contexto.set"??

Answer (score 3):

Yo lo hago asi:

```
var LastRegister = Contexto.tabla1
            .OrderByDescending(x => x.fecha)
            .First().fecha;
```

Answer (score 3):

No, el uso de `LastOrDefault()` no es lo apropiado en este caso. Esa función está diseñada para conseguir el último registro que cumple alguna **condición**. Pero en tu caso, lo que deseas es obtener el último registro según el **orden** basado en cierta columna.

Para esto, la idea tras la respuesta de @Software lover es la correcta. O sea, de usar `OrderByDescending()` para ordenar los registros por fecha, y luego usar `FirstOrDefault()` para devolver el primer registro (o último registro dependiendo de tu perspectiva).

Corrigiendo un poco la sentencia propuesta en la respuesta de @Software lover, la sentencia vendría siendo:

```
var registroMasActualizado = 
    contexto.Set<Tabla1>()
        .OrderByDescending(t => t.Fecha)
        .FirstOrDefault();
```

Esto producirá una consulta SQL muy eficiente.  Por ejemplo, en SQL Server, la consulta generada se parecerá a esto (nota el uso del `ORDER BY` combinado con el `TOP (1)`:

```sql
SELECT TOP (1)
    [Extent1].[Id_Registro] AS [Id_Registro],
    [Extent1].[Fecha] AS [Fecha],
    [Extent1].[motivo] AS [motivo],
    [Extent1].[estado] AS [estado]
    FROM [dbo].[Tabla1] AS [Extent1]
    ORDER BY [Extent1].[Fecha] DESC
```

Answer (score 1):

Esta medio raro como haces la consulta 
Yo haría esto

```
Contexto.Table1.orderByDesc().FirstorDefault();
```

Y así obtendrás el último registro que tenga la tabla 
Disculpa que no lo ponga en formato de código de la página es que lo hice desde el móvil